# Python list joining — include separator at the start or at the end

Tags: python, python-3.x

The output for `', '.join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])` is:

```
a, b, c, d
```

Is there a standard way in Python to achieve the following outputs instead?

```
# option 1, separator is also at the start
, a, b, c, d

# option 2, separator is also at the end
a, b, c, d, 

# option 3, separator is both at the start and the end
, a, b, c, d,
```

Comment: Add a `""` element to the beginning or end of your list.

Comment: Or add the separator to the beginning/end of your result. There is no explicit option for this in `join`.

Comment: "Is there a *standard* way? No. The standard is to not include leading or trailing separators. There are many ways to accomplish it however using the standard library, and builtin functionality. Just make sure whatever you write is readable and understandable.

Comment: It's not the "default" output, it's *the* output. What you want isn't joining any more; it's something more.

Answer (score 15):

There is no standard approach, but a natural way is to add empty strings at the end or at the beginning (or at the end *and* the beginning). Using some more modern syntax:

```
>>> ', '.join(['', *['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']])
', a, b, c, d'
>>> ', '.join([*['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ''])
'a, b, c, d, '
>>> ', '.join(['', *['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ''])
', a, b, c, d, '
```

Or just use string formatting:

```
>>> sep = ','
>>> data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> f"{sep}{sep.join(data)}"
',a,b,c,d'
>>> f"{sep.join(data)}{sep}"
'a,b,c,d,'
>>> f"{sep}{sep.join(data)}{sep}"
',a,b,c,d,'
```

Comment: Hey @juanpa, could you explain the use of the asterisk? It seems I'm less modern than that

Comment: @JuanC it's just argument unpacking, but you can do it with `list`/`dict`/`set` literals now as well

Comment: @JuanC the * operator unpacks the content of a tuple/list

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way:

```
list1 = ['1','2','3','4']  

s = ","

r = f"{s}{s.join(list1)}"

p = f"{s.join(list1)}{s}"

q = f"{s}{s.join(list1)}{s}"


print(r)
print(p)
print(q)
```